# Modifying a List in Preaperation for Writing to an Excel File

Tags: python, pandas

Currently i have a program that writes to an excel spread sheet, problem is, it doesn't write one value of the list into one cell, it crams it all into an entire cell. How can i modify my list at the end of my program so that it writes one value per one cell in excel (that is one value, next row one value and so on). See below for big yikes of a screenshot. [image: click here for image )big yikes)] I want to make it so that when it writes to excel, the result is: 
[image: wanted result]

Many thanks in advance. (sorry for poor formatting)

Current Code:

```
for i in range(0,len(file_dates_list)): #gets all of the rest of the data
    n = 1
    if (file_gap_list[i] > 1 or i == 0) and file_gap_list[i+n] <= 1:
        while ((i + n) < len(file_dates_list)) and (file_gap_list[i + n] <= 1):
            n = n + 1
        max_value = (max(file_hs_list[i:i + n]))
        max_value_location = file_hs_list.index(max_value)
        list_final_multiple.append([file_dates_list[max_value_location], file_hs_list[max_value_location]])


list_final_combined = list_final_single + list_final_multiple
list_final_Date = [i[0] for i in list_final_combined]
list_final_Hs = [i[1] for i in list_final_combined]


excel_file = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [list_final_Date],
                           'H_s': [list_final_Hs]})
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('FilteredList.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
excel_file.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
writer.save()
```

Comment: Show what you tried as properly formatted code in the question.

Comment: yeah using pandas

Comment: It is already a list, no need to wrap inside another list. Just change to: `excel_file = pd.DataFrame({'Date': list_final_Date,
                           'H_s': list_final_Hs})`

Comment: hm, i still get the same output

Comment: works fine for me... You can even see the square brackets in the first image which means you are just writing a list inside a single cell. Try printing `len(list_final_Date)`

Comment: nvm, youre right, my bad

Comment: thanks for that, it makes so much more sense now